# MySQL Find and show all duplicates

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to find duplicates in a DB - but also show ALL the duplicate records. My current query:

```
SELECT 'duplicate' as dup,c.Id, c.CreatedDate, c.email, c.Lead_Grade__c, count(c.email) 
FROM contact as c
Inner Join (select c.Id, c.email FROM contact as c group by c.email having count(c.email) > 1) as dup
ON c.email = dup.email
WHERE Lead_Grade__c is null;
```

This works to provide 1 row for each duplicate record. I want 2 (or more) rows for each duplicate record. So, if record X AND record Y both have the same email, then I'd like to show both.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to show both? As seperate rows or on the same row?  and if there's more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will join contact to itself and only show records where the email is the same that have more than 1 record (Assuming ID is a unique value)

This results set therefor should only be duplicates.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM contact A
INNER JOIN CONTACT B
 on A.email = B.email
 and a.id <> b.ID
ORDER BY A.Email
```